# C# Setup with external DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, installation

I am trying to make a setup for a C# application in .NET 3.5.

The application runs an other application which was compiled for .NET 4.5 and uses some DLLs. I want to add this application to the application folder in the setup.

I can't add the DLL's to the setup as a file, there is an error popping up. ("The operation could not be completed")

[image: Error Window]

If I add the DDLs to the project folder and then use them as content, I get an "Unrecoverable build error" when I create the project.

How am I supposed to add these DLLs? I do not care how, but I need them in the project folder.

Thanks.

PS: I am using the standard setup for VisualStudio 2008.

Comment: I don't know what is this error, but you can use custom action to copy these required dlls.

Comment: How would you do this? Where should I store the DLLs before installation?

Comment: Beside of your setup file. You can zip them also. But maybe there is better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio, when you add your external DLL as a reference in a project, it will automatically be added to the setup.

Comment: I can't add those DLLs as a reference in my project because they are .NET 4.5 and my project is .NET 3.5. If I add them, they are "not found" --> The path field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, isn't there any way to find an earlier version of the assembly targeting .NET 3.5? Or if you have access to the source, remove/change the .NET 4.5 specific code and recompile?

Otherwise, you can try to wrap you dll around a COM interface, as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204406/How-To-Use-a-NET-Based-DLL-From-NET-Based-Appl). This article targets .NET 4 dll used with .NET 2.0 but the mechanism should still work in your configuration. I have used it successfully myself for 2.0/4.0 interop.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dfadfb34-5328-4c53-8274-931c6ae00836/stop-vs-2010-build-errors-when-referencing-newer-framework-dlls?forum=msbuild) is another trick you can try.

Comment: It is hardly done. I am not sure I would waste so much time with reviewing code. There are several dll's being used by that project.  And the only thing I need is that exe to be executed. I never imagined it would be so hard to include a file as a "FILE" in a setup without popping up errors.

Comment: Well, you can try to use another trick (see my updated post). It didn't work for me with VS2012 but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that in either case you will need .NET 4.5 installed on target computer, in order to work. So you can move your project from 3.5 to 4.5. I understand that you use VS2008 which doesn't have .NET 4.5, but you can use express (free) edition of Visual Studio from here -> [Microsoft Download Page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using a simple trick:

The errors came only from the DLLs written in .NET 4.5. The executable (.exe) did not cause any errors. What I did is to package all the DLL's into the exe using the ILMerge tool.

Then I added the .exe file to the library and everything worked like a charm.

[ILMerge download site (Microsoft)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630)